# Has an actor ever been uncredited to keep their face secret?

Tags: credits, film-industry

In the 2019 show *The Mandalorian*, it is a recurring theme that the protagonist never takes his helmet off in front of others. But since we know who the actor is, anyone can just google his name and see his face.

So, has any film or show ever been made, where an actor was uncredited in order to hide their face from the viewers?

Comment: Matt Damon was officially credited as Dickie Greenleaf for his appearance in Deadpool 2 as a redneck, thus masking his identity. Or do you want more than just a cameo role?

Comment: Darth Vader’s face isn’t David Prowse nor James Earl Jones. I don’t think being able to Google the actor is relevant.

Comment: @HorusKol I'm looking for a more important role, preferably protagonist or antagonist

Comment: Does Magic Secrets Revealed count?

Comment: I've seen a few TV episodes in which the return of a major supporting character is teased – shown in shadow or the like – and the actor is credited under a false name, because their true name would be a spoiler.  One example was Anthony Ainley (as The Master) in *Doctor Who*, credited with an anagram.

Comment: But do we know for sure that underneath the helmet, the Mandalorian looks like Pedro Pascal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So, has any film or show ever been made, where an actor was uncredited in order to hide their face from the viewers?

## Yes, the TV series Charlie's Angels

**John Forsythe** (as Charlie) was readily identifiable by his voice but was never credited or seen.

> During the show's five-year run, the identity of Charlie was one of TV's most closely guarded secrets. **John Forsythe's name was deliberately left off the credits and even the other cast members were not told who was behind the voice.**
>
> [**Source**](https://www.independent.co.uk/news/obituaries/john-forsythe-actor-who-played-blake-carrington-in-dynasty-and-the-elusive-charlie-in-charlies-1938417.html)